# $.ajax success function returns null

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a basic log in form set up and I'm sending the two variables(login+password) using ajax request to a different page which checks and returns the status accordingly. My ajax code

```
$('form.login_form').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
    url = "textlogin.php",
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,

        success: function(response){
            if(response==""){
                $('#login_err').html("its null");
            }else{
                $('#login_err').html(response);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

is not working and `success` function always returns null. The code was working fine until i was not using `ajax` and `jquery dialog` for log in. 
Things i tried:
 1. setting the `Content-type`
 2. setting the `dataType`
 3. Using $.post and what not.

Comment: Using a modern browser such as Firefox or Chrome, you should observe the development tools to determine whether the request/response are as you would expect.

Comment: You can get the form data with a simple var data = that.serializeArray(), no need to loop through fields by hand. Also, check the browser console to validate the post and the response.

Comment: tried doing that too.

Comment: It looks like that you are getting empty NOT null response in your success callback, try to call `textlogin.php` from browser window and pass parameters as query string, check what you see in browser window. and please share `textlogin.php` code as well.

Comment: Yeah sorry i'm getting empty result, not null.

Comment: @ArushKamboj, please share your `textlogin.php`, then I can give you an idea whats going on?

Comment: Finally its working!! and i have no idea why :O

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "login.php?",
        data:"username="+username+"&password="+password,
        success: function(data)
        {
        }
});
```

Please Try this.

If you are using Mozilla Firefox then Please install firebug add on . After installing firebug open it. Now you can find the console tab.make it enable. Now When you run ajax then you can see here.

And suppose you pass array directly then better way is to use implode function in php so use this function.

Please Give me reply if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify type of data. I hope this will helps you

```
function a()
{
  var ip=new Object(); 
ip.name=value;
var data=JSON.stringify(ip);

    $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/file.php",
            data:data,
            dataType:"json",
           success: function(data)
            {
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: no need to specify the `dataType` as `jaspon` as $.ajax takes care of it itself. My problem is solved mate. thanks for dropping by.